# Convert a Hex string into a uint8_t array in C

Tags: arrays, c, string, hex

I want to read a file convert it into hex string and then save the result in an a 8-bit (or a byte) array . I'm reading a text file character by character and converting it into a hex and storing the result string successfully, but Now I want to put the resulted string array in a 2D array matrix.
I have try this.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint-gcc.h>


int main()
{
    int i=0,j;

    FILE *filePointer;
    char ch;
    int counter=0;
    char hex[50];
    filePointer = fopen("plaintext1.txt", "r");
    if (filePointer == NULL)
        printf("File is not available \n");
    else
    {
        while ((ch = fgetc(filePointer)) != EOF)
        {
         printf("%c", ch);
            hex[i] = ch;
            i++;
            counter++;
        }
    }
    /*set strH with nulls*/
    unsigned char strH[200];
    memset(strH,0,sizeof(strH));

    /*converting str character into Hex and adding into strH*/
    for(i=0,j=0;i<counter;i++,j+=2)
    {
       sprintf((char*)strH+j,"%02X",hex[i]);
    }
    strH[j]='\0'; /*adding NULL in the end*/
    printf("\nHexadecimal converted string is: \n");
    printf("%s\n",strH);
    //here i want to store the result in an array but failed here
    printf("\nThe matrix of the Hex is : \n");
    uint8_t text_hex[counter];
    int a ,b;
    for (a=0;a<strlen(strH) ;a++ ){
           text_hex[a] = strH[a];
           printf("%x",text_hex[a]); //this thing is annoying 
    }

    fclose(filePointer);
    return 0;
}
```

[In the image there is result of program run, i read text from a file "plaintext1.txt" the content of file is "This is a string"  ..program give me hex but not giving me correc array of those hex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBMlg.png)

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

First to answer you question the line `text_hex[a] = strH[a]` is converting the ascii values. a Hex string will have characters [0 - 9], [A - F] and [a -f] which correspond with ascii values [48 - 57], [65 - 71], and [97 - 103] (these are ascii values in decimal). To convert the hex string to the corresponding uint8_t values you would need to convert the ascii values properly. On a byte by byte basic this could be done with:

````
text_hex[a] = strH[a] <= '9' ? strH[a] - 48 : (strH[a] <= 'F' ? strH[a] - 55 : strH[a] - 87);
// strH[a] <= '9' is checking if the char is in the decimal range or letter range
// strH[a] - 48 is the case where its decimal range which means the string -> int conversion is  ```char_value - 48```
// (strH[a] <= 'F' ? strH[a] - 55 : strH[a] - 87); is for the letter range
// strH[a] <= 'F' is checking if its a upper case letter
// strH[a] - 55 converts an uppercase ascii hex char to its int value (55 == 'A' - 10)
// strH[a] - 87 is the lower case equivilent
````

A few things worth noting: The solution above is not the most efficient solution (mostly shooting for simplicity here). Also it will break if the character is not a valid ascii digit.

Now some other things:

```
for (a=0;a<strlen(strH) ;a++ ){
```

is not incorrect but almost definitely NOT what you want to do. Each loop you will recompute `strlen` which in turn iterates through `strH` to find `\0`. This effectively turns an `O(N)` (with N being length of string) into an `O(N^2)` function. Much better is:

```
int strH_length = strlen(strH);
for (a=0;a< strH_length ;a++ ){
```

The conversion from `hex` to `strH` doesnt really make sense (maybe I'm missing something) but it seems to me to be ascii encoding -> ascii encoding. You could likely just do the conversion directly from `hex`.

Lastly

```
uint8_t text_hex[counter];
```

Isn't good practice. Counter is not known at compile time so trying to statically allocate an array of size `counter` (depending on the value of counter) could break things.

Best to either dynamically allocate with `calloc` or statically allocate with a constant.

Comment: I found the answer quite helpful , but can you help me further as in text_hex[a] i am getting  only a 4-bit hex . e-g for 'T'  the hex is '54' (which is 8-bit) and my result when i store, it is , text_hex[0] = 5 and text_hex[1] = 4.. I want to store 1 byte complete in the text_hex[0] e-g text_hex[0] = '54'..

i am new to C programming that's why my coding is not quite efficient